# Multi-task learning: keep same batch size or same epochs?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, multitasking

I am building a multi-task model with two tasks. However, the data size for them are different: let's say task 1 has 100k training data while task 2 only has 10k. In this case, should I keep the same batch size and train task 1 10 times then task 2 once; or keep the same epoch and reduce the batch size of task 2 to 1/10 of that of task 1?